# Trying to pass an array to function in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have created the following function to run through the "iN" array and the "nS" array 10 times to combine both arrays into 1. My plan was to push the array to "callUpArrayResults" function with this line "callUpArrayResults(questionsArray)" but I receive a "Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String]'". 
As well as a "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable" for this line "callUpArrayResults = arr" am I going about this wrong? Or can I call up the created array result directly from the function if so How would I go about that? I'm new to swift but I am trying to learn any guidance would be appreciated.

```
func creatArray () {

var iN: [AnyObject] = [
//a
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx1",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx2",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx3",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx4",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx5",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx6",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx7",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx8",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx9",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx10",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx11",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx12",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx13",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx14",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx15",
"Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx16"]

var nS:[AnyObject] = [
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy1",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy2",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy3",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy4",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy5",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy6",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy7",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy8",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy9",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy10",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy11",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy12",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy13",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy14",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy15",
"Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyyyyyyy16"]

var questionsArray: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

for var i = 0; i < 10; i++ {

    let arrayCount = iN.count
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayCount)))
    let xx = iN[random]
    let yy = nS[random]
        let QnA: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "x" : xx,
            "y" : yy
        ]
        //remove from array
        iN.removeAtIndex(random)
        Ns.removeAtIndex(random)
        //add dictionary for each question into array
        questionsArray.append (QnA)

    print(questionsArray)

}
callUpArrayResults(questionsArray)
}

creatArray()

fun callUpArrayResults(arr:[String]){

 callUpArrayResults = arr

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every language has a natural way code wants to be written. As part of the process for learning a language, try to learn how code should be written in that language.

In this example, you want to combine the elements of two arrays into an array of dictionaries, randomly select 10 of those dictionaries. In Swift, `zip()`, `map()` and `prefix()` cover everything except the randomization. You need something like a shuffle method for the array.

Here is one that does the Fisher-Yates (fast and uniform) shuffle:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)

        if result.count > 1 {
            for i in 0 ..< result.count - 1 {
                let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(result.count - i))) + i
                if i != j {
                    swap(&result[i], &result[j])
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

With `shuffle()` in hand, I can solve the problem.

```
let allQuestions = zip(iN, nS).map {xx, yy in ["x": xx, "y": yy]}
let shuffledQuestions = allQuestions.shuffle()
let first10ShuffledQuestions = shuffledQuestions.prefix(10)

let questionsArray: [AnyObject] = Array(first10ShuffledQuestions)
```

The first part, `zip(iN, nS).map {xx, yy in ["x": xx, "y": yy]}` creates an array of dictionaries using the key `"x"` for `iN` and `"y"` for `nS`. The next part, `shuffle()` returns an array of dictionaries in a random order. The last part, `prefix(10)` returns an array slice of the shuffled array containing the first 10 elements. Because `prefix()` returns an array slice and not an array, use `Array()` to create an array from the array slice for the final assignment to `questionsArray`.

This can all be done in one line.

```
let questionsArray: [AnyObject] = Array(zip(iN, nS).map {xx, yy in ["x": xx, "y": yy]}.shuffle().prefix(10))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a mess. If you're going to be working with arrays of strings, don't make them type `[AnyObject]`. Make them type `[String]`. Then you won't have problems with casting.

Your variable names and method names should always start with a lower-case letter. That is a strong convention in both Swift and Objective-C. Class names (and Swift type names) should start with upper-case letters.

A local variable defined inside a function ceases to exist once that function returns. If you want a function to have a result that's accessible outside the function, either have it return a result, or have it act on an instance variable.

You're not doing either of those things, so the result of your function isn't accessible outside of your function.

If you don't know how to do either of those things then it's time to start reading. I suggest downloading the free Swift iBook from Apple and reading the first half of it. It will teach you the Swift language. If this is your first programming language then you might want a book that teaches you programming using Swift as the language.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll use your suggestions in the future, I really do appreciate the critique.